# How to restrict the construction of a domain object to an external service?

Tags: java, c#, object-oriented, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I have this object

```
RelativeFoo{int relativeCode, Origin relativeTo}
```

And I want to map it to this other object

```
AbsoluteFoo{int absoluteCode}
```

In order to do this, I need to use a service whose implementation calls an external API

```
AbsoluteFoo absFoo = fooProvider.obtainAbsoluteVersionOf(new RelativeFoo(1, Origin.BAR))
```

In order to be sure that an `AbsoluteFoo` instance is indeed absolute (meaning, created by the external service), I think that I need to restrict the instantiation of `AbsoluteFoo` to the `fooProvider`.

One way of doing it is making `obtainAbsoluteVersionOf` a static method of `AbsoluteFoo` (`AbsoluteFoo.from(relativeFoo)` with `AbsoluteFoo` having a private constructor) or a instance method of `RelativeFoo` (`relativeFoo.toAbsolute()` with `AbsoluteFoo` having a private constructor and being a inner class of `RelativeFoo`).

However, since the method `obtainAbsoluteVersionOf` uses an external API, I can't really make it into an domain object method, can I? I mean, I don't like the idea of injecting dependencies in a domain object, so that's something that I'm not considering as a possibility.

Currently, `obtainAbsoluteVersionOf` is a domain service that is implemented in the infrastructure layer, and I don't know how to restrict the construction of `AbsoluteFoo` to this service in this setting.

Any ideas how I could model this better?

Also, I think my question is related to this other one, which wasn't really answered:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776829/external-data-mapping-to-domain

Comment: This sounds like a horrible idea to me. If you want ever be able to write unit tests which require `AbsoluteFoo` objects as test data, your tests will depend on this external API. I would usually try to design a system in a way that code which is based on `AbsoluteFoo` is agnostic of who or what consttructed it. Maybe you can elaborate why you want to design the system this way?

Comment: @DocBrown Like, isn't common to have the construction of an object restricted to a factory? In mycase the factory would call an external service and in tests I could mock this factory. Let me propose other solution now taking tests in consideration. I could have something like AbsoluteFoo.build(relativeFoo, relativeCodeMapper), which relativeCodeMapper being the one responsible for calling the external API. In the tests, relativeCodeMapper could be mocked, allowing me to create AbsoluteFoo without the external API. Too messy?

Comment: Ok, it seems you want the construction of `AbsoluteFoo` to be restricted to a specific factory, which is not necessarily an external service. That reads a little bit different than what you wrote literally in your question.

Comment: Yeah, now I see that. Maybe a better question would be "Should a factory take a service as paramater"?

Comment: I made the question a little bit different on stackoverflow and I got an answer that actually helped me to understand where was my confusion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75084892/should-i-restrict-the-constuction-of-a-domain-object-to-an-external-service

Comment: OP, this does not seem like a language-agnostic question. Can you tag a programming language?

Comment: @JohnWu Yes. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: This reads like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. What are you ultimately trying to protect against? You're also asking, "How do I do X?", and then, "I could do it like Y", and then, "but I don't wanna!!!". And, I'm not super clear what your objection to Y is.

Comment: @svidgen I don't think it's a XY problem. What I want is to make sure that the consumer of my domain (application layer) has no option to create an instance of AbsoluteFoo other than calling fooProvider.obtainAbsoluteVersionOf. As I mentioned in other commet, I made other question in stackoverflow whose accepted answer made me not worry if the consumer of my domain layer is or isn't using the service, since the application layer is trust worth code. Regardless, the question remains: How to restrict the construction of a domain object to an external service?

Comment: "What I want is to make sure that the consumer of my domain (application layer) has no option to create an instance of AbsoluteFoo other than calling fooProvider.obtainAbsoluteVersionOf." Yes, but ***why?*** You already have an answer. You stated it in the OP! But, you don't like it. ***Why???*** You were assured elsewhere that you don't even need to solve the problem. But, you're still trying to solve it. ***WHY!??***

Comment: @svidgen I'm trying to model a domain where fooProvider is the one responsible for creating AbsoluteFoo resources. As this characteristic is part of the domain that I'm trying to model, I expect the model to represent that, meaning that an instance of AbsoluteFoo can only be obtained through a call to fooProvider.

Comment: I understand that this is what you want mechanically. But, it doesn't quite jibe with the problem statement -- though it's hard to tell precisely what the problem is. From the OP, you want to ensure `ConcreteX` comes from `ServiceX`. Great. **Why?** There are probably a dozen ways you can approach this, and which you choose depends on the language, codebase idioms, team dogmas, and the ultimate purpose. E.g., are you trying to *sign* or *authorize* an object? Or similarly to ensure the object exists in some database? Or that it meets some other secret validation? (Rules stuck behind an API?)

Comment: @svidgen "Why?" Because in the domain that I'm try to model, ServiceX builds ConcreteX. I'm just modelling that and I don't think it depends that much on the language, maybe depends on things like constructors, visibility of methods and etc, but that's common among oop languages. As for what SeviceX does, it calls an external system and builds ConcreteX with whatever is returned. Feel free to explain where is my confusion in wanting to restrict the instantiation of ConcreteX to an external service. It can even be the accepted answer, why not

Comment: The details included in your SO post are much more concretely answerable. Though, I disagree with a large portion of the accepted answer there. In the abstract (the OP here), this is nearly impossible to answer. In the concrete (your SO post), the real answer is, "It depends on your risk assessment." If you want to be "sure" X comes from Y, Y should **sign it**, and your domain entity should explicitly promise it has an X signed by Y. That's not really an "object construction" problem, its a business requirement that should probably be in the domain itself. Maybe as simple as `X.isSignedBy(Y)`

Comment: ... Or perhaps when you create `new X()`, you need to pass in the signature, the constructor validates it at construction, and the result is an immutable object. On the other hand, if the business just wants to be *reasonably sure* that X's come from Y. Psh. You own the code. Just don't create X's in the prod codebase apart from calls to Y. Done.

Comment: @svidgen I don't know why the original post is so much less answerable than the SO post. I like original post more because is closer to my actual business rule (it really is a matter of relative and absolute, and there's a system responsible for the mapping). But anyway, I like the ideia of signing it. Is specially good because a signature can contain information about who made the "relative -> absolute" mapping in a abstract way (like, independent of the service implementation details). I'm sorry I coudn't make a question clear enough for which you could provide this answer imediatelly.

Comment: "I don't know why the original post is so much less answerable than the SO post" It's just that the abstract question has too many possible answers. If someone happened to provide the correct answer, it would kind of be accidental, and it would not be canonically correct to live here in posterity. (Unless someone exhaustively enumerated all the possibilities.)

Comment: I'm glad you like the idea. I had a *hunch* this was the problem behind the problem. But, even if my hunch was correct, I still can't say whether "signing" is the right answer. It's *an* answer. But, if you own the code, and if your API calls are all over SSL using publicly trusted certs, and if your DB is locked down, etc., the additional signing *may* be overkill. Similarly, if the app is just a simple inventory tracking app or something, it's probably *very* overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think that I need to restrict the instantiation of `AbsoluteFoo` to the `fooProvider`.

What you're effectively saying here is that **you don't trust your developers** to only instantiate `AbsoluteFoo` for actually absolute values. If that is correct, you've got a way bigger problem on your hands, and that is that you've got developers who don't know what they're doing.

To be fair, some coding guidelines definitely exist to help avoid boneheaded mistakes that are easy to make (e.g. forgetting to update all WET instances, easily breaking magic string values without realizing, ...). There's value to ensuring that developers don't make easy mistakes. I suspect your intentions are along this line.

However, what you're asking for here is a couple steps further than that. You want to design your code so that the compiler vets your business logic to a point of *disbelieving* any new code unless it conforms to your current idea of what the code should be, in an attempt to use some kind of authorization / access control to not allow developers to do something that the language would allow them to do.

Even if that were a good idea, it would require a truly monumental amount of rule-designing in order to ensure that your developers could only use the code in the way that you've designed it. Which leads me to two subsequent questions:

- Can the developers make changes to those rules?
- Who fact-checks the developers who write the fact-checking rules?

This is going to become an infinitely recurring "who watches the watchmen" scenario of distrust, and it's not a healthy development environment.

The solution here is to either train your developers to be more reliable or to only staff reliable developers in the first place, so you don't need to run around constantly second-guessing any code that any of your developers might be writing.

**There's a reason code reviews exist**. They exist because we have not found a way to automate this kind of review, because this requires a nuanced understanding of both the acceptance criteria and the particular scenario in order to review it. If we were able to relegate this process to an automated ruleset, we'd be doing that already and we wouldn't be manually reviewing code. The existence of the process implies that **human eyes are needed to judge the validity of new code**.

Comment: Today I understand and agree with you. Back when I asked this question I was kinda thinking that, in a perfect object oriented system, the code would simulate real world behaviours. Now I understand that it is more about telling a story with objects whose names match real world concepts. Because it is not a simulation, but rather a story, there's no need to create inviolable rules. The only requirement is to have something that, at least from a higher level, happens in a way that is analogous to what I would expect from the respective real world business rule. Makes sense?

Comment: Pretty much. Logic more often than not mirrors real world processes, whose design often stems from real world constraints that might not apply in the digital realm, but they are maintained nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Design patterns suitable to model `AbsoluteFoo` instantiation are builder design pattern and optionally, depending on where `AbsoluteFoo` has to be instantiated, factory design pattern:

Factory design pattern, specifically abstract factory design pattern, for polymorphic object creation, encapsulates object creation code, thus following single responsibility principle (SRP) of Clean Architecture, and reduces code duplication, thus following don't repeat yourself (DRY) principle of The Pragmatic Programmer.

Builder design pattern for sequential object creation, encapsulates object creation code, thus following SRP.

The layer handling external services invocation converts external responses to internally known representations returning to calling layers application specific entities, or domain objects, that can be created using instances of entities factories or entities builders from the layer handling the application's data model. Summed up for the actual scenario `fooProvider` should hold a reference of `AbsoluteFoo` factory or builder.

Update for comments:
Reduced accessibility to instantiation could be achieved, using access modifiers and inheritance, through package by feature.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering. About the answer, how could I restrict the construction to the fooProvider? I can see that it will need a reference of AbsoluteFoo factory or builder, but how can I make sure that only the fooProvider service can create instances of AbsoluteFoo? Should I do this at all? My intention is to avoid developers creating instances of AbsoluteFoo by means other than the fooProvider (this service could be mocked for the tests, so the test part is ok).